# Using jQuery to limit the number of list elements

Tags: jquery, list, limit

I have a list element containing a number of between 20-30 events. I only want to show 5 of those, and have a «More» link I can click to watch the the next five. It doesn't matter if the five next events are appended.

Can't find a jQuery script that actually does this, or am I just blind? I don't want to use carousel plugins or anything like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, fortunately for us programmers, who write code for food and fame, not every imaginable piece of functionality has been written yet as a plugin :)

But this is quite easy:

```
var from = 0, step = 5;

function showNext(list) {
  list
    .find('li').hide().end()
    .find('li:lt(' + (from + step) + '):not(li:lt(' + from + '))')
      .show();
  from += step;
}

function showPrevious(list) {
  from -= step;
  list
    .find('li').hide().end()
    .find('li:lt(' + from + '):not(li:lt(' + (from - step) + '))')
      .show();
}

// show initial set
showNext($('ul'));

// clicking on the 'more' link:
$('#more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  showNext($('ul'));
});
```

Of course this is better extracted into plugin-like function, but I'm gonna leave that as an exercise for a reader ;)

Comment: This looks nice, but how do I initially hide every list item except the first five?

Comment: The initial call to `showNext(yourList)` will hide everything but the first five elements. I guess you would want to call it on `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but it was only me who forgot to wrap all the li's in a ul ;) Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question. If I want to be able to link back to the previous five elements, how should I sort this?

Answer (score 6):

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<ul class="more">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  <li>seven</li>
  <li>eight</li>
  <li>nine</li>
  <li>ten</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("ul.more").each(function() {
    $("li:gt(4)", this).hide(); /* :gt() is zero-indexed */
    $("li:nth-child(5)", this).after("<li class='more'><a href='#'>More...</a></li>"); /* :nth-child() is one-indexed */
  });
  $("li.more a").live("click", function() {
    var li = $(this).parents("li:first");
    li.parent().children().show();
    li.remove();
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</script
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what this does:

1. Hides the 6th and subsequent list items;
2. Inserts a list item after the 5th saying "More...";
3. Uses live events to add an event handler to the "More..." links so that when they are clicked they show all list items in that list and then remove themselves.

**Edit:** Fixed up a few little errors. The above is a fully working example now (just make sure the jquery link is correct).

Answer (score 3):

You want to start off with each element in the list hidden (CSS: display: none). Then have your more link undernearth the list element.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a#myMoreLink").click(function()
    {
        var items = $("ul#myList > li:hidden");

        if(items.length > 0)
            items.slice(0, 5).show();
        else
            $(this).html("No more");

        return false;
    });

    $("a#myMoreLink").click();
});
```

With HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li style="display: none"></li>
    <li style="display: none"></li>
</ul>
<a href="http://" id="myMoreLink">More</a>
```

Something like that. $("a#myMoreLink").click(); is called to show the initial 5 items upon loading the page.

Comment: Buggy code: it will always switch between first 5 and second 5 elements. Elements from 10 to 15 will never be displayed.

Comment: I  didn't test the code, it's pseudo-code. OP said it didn't matter if they were appended (easily changeable).

It does work. I just tested it. There's just a typo mylist -> myList.

You down-rep me for that and make up some bug about 10-15 elements? This isn't a competition, jeez.

Here's the full code:

http://pastebin.com/m56bb8358

Answer (score 2):

This works but sure you will have to tweak it some what :)

html:

```
<div style="width:200px;border:3px groove blue;">
   <ul id="list">
    <li>Thai</li>
    <li>Turkish</li>
    <li>Portuguese</li>
    <li>American English</li>
    <li>Arabic</li>
    <li>Canadian French</li>
    <li>Chinese Simplified</li>
    <li>Chinese Traditional</li>
    <li>Czech</li>
    <li>Danish</li>
    <li>Dutch</li>
    <li>English</li>
    <li>Finnish</li>
    <li>French</li>
    <li>German</li>
    <li>Greek</li>
    <li>Hebrew</li>
    <li>Hungarian</li>
    <li>Italian</li>
    <li>Japanese</li>
    <li>Norweigan</li>
    <li>Polish</li>
    <li>Russian</li>
    <li>Spanish</li>
   </ul>    
   <a href="#" id="lnkMore">More</a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var len = 0;
    var curStart = 0;
    var count = 5;
    var items=new Array();
    function BackupList() {
        var lst = $("ul#list");
        len= $("ul#list li").length;
        if (len <= count)
            return;

        $("ul#list li").each(function() {
            items.push($(this));
            $(this).remove();
        });

        var html="";
        for (curStart; curStart < count && curStart < len; curStart++) {
            html += "<li>" + $(items[curStart]).html() + "</li>";
        }
        $(html).appendTo($(lst));
    }

    function ShowMore() {
        if (curStart >= len) {
            curStart = 0;
        }

        $("ul#list li").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });

        var l = curStart;
        var html = "";
        for (curStart; curStart < (l + count) && curStart < len; curStart++) {
            html += "<li>" + items[curStart].html() + "</li>";
        }
        $(html).appendTo($("ul#list"));
    }
</script>
```

Wire jquery for event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        BackupList();
        $("a#lnkMore").click(function() { ShowMore(); });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a hideMaxListItems plugin that may be what you were looking for. You can set the maximum number of list items, animation speed for the slide animation, and expand/collapse button HTML. The slide animation is done sequentially per list item, to give a smooth animation.

http://www.joshuawinn.com/maximum-list-items-jquery-hide-after-x-number-bullets/